# PHP disabling ouput buffering

Tags: php

I've turned off the *output buffering* in PHP by setting `output_buffering = off` in php.int but when runnng the simple code like that:

```
<?php
echo "Hello ";
sleep(3);
echo "World";
```

I get the full output - Hello World at once, after 3 secs not like I expected first `Hello`- 3 secs - `World` Why doesn't it works like that?

PS.
I've check it both in the browser and using the *Curl*.

Comment: have you tried running that from a commandline to test?

Comment: Ok thx for suggestion. When running from command line like that: _php output_test.php_ it indeed works. So why it doesn't which the browser or curl?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding  `flush()` and `ob_flush()` see at [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php)

will look something like this

```
<?php
echo "Hello ";
ob_flush();
flush();
sleep(3);
echo "World";
?>
```

Comment: This helped but why doesn't it work without using _ob_flush_ & _flush_ functions chence the _output buffering_ was disabled in _php.ini_?

Answer (score -1):

Ok, It seems that I've resolved the issue. The secret was setting *implicit_flush* to *On* in php config file. But that raised a question for me. In such a case what's *output_buffering* option for since it doesn't work as in my example?

Comment: It's useful with the `ob_XXX()` functions.